# App crashes on launch when activated from Toast Notification

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I created a test app and I am able to get my app to launch from a toast notification, but I can't get it working with my real app???

My MainPage has a frame that navigates to a page with 2 frames.  I want the second frame to load a certain page when the Toast Notification is clicked.

Here's my OnLaunched code

```
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {

        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        // Otherwise an action is provided
        if (e.Arguments != "")
        {
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
            FramePage.Instance.setSecondFrame("Email");
        }
        else
        {
            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }

        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
```

It works from the OnActivated just fine.  Any ideas??

Comment: Ask Microsoft, as sometimes on both my phone and my Windows PC there used to be such issues with their own apps.

Answer (score 4):

Form the code you've posted, it seems you are handling activation from a toast notification with `OnLaunched` method. However

> In Windows 10, Microsoft has updated the toast activation behavior so that when a toast (or an action inside toast) triggers a foreground activation, OnActivated is invoked instead of OnLaunched, with a new activation kind – ToastNotification. Thus, we are able to easily distinguish a toast activation and perform tasks accordingly.

In Windows 10, with the addition of adaptive templates and custom actions, there are 3 different kind of activations that the app might be expected to handle.

1. Foreground activation from a toast notification using Windows 10 adaptive template;
2. Background activation from a toast notification using Windows 10 adaptive template;
3. Legacy: Foreground activation from a toast notification using legacy template.

For the first kind, we should handle it by overriding [OnActivated method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onactivated.aspx) not [OnLaunched method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.onlaunched.aspx). You need to use `OnLaunched` method to handle activation only when you are using legacy templates. But if you are developing a new Windows 10 universal app, the new adaptive template is highly recommend.

> All legacy toast templates can be easily achieved by using the new adaptive template. By using the new adaptive template, you can have a consistent way and place to handle toast activation.

For more info, please see [Send a local toast notification from UWP apps: Handling activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast#step-4-handling-activation). And also the [code sample on GitHub](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/quickstart-sending-local-toast-win10).